# Putting codes in email subjects

Tags: email, spam-prevention

We send out large quantities of email to our customers (work environment surveys). Sometimes our mailinglist for a client isn't quite up to date and we get bounce mails (address not found and such). However, since these all bounce back to the same address it's difficult to keep track on which bounce belongs to which client. (The email subject is usually pretty generic, like "Welcome to the work environment survey")

This is why I would like to insert a identifier in the subject line of the email. So the subject would be "Welcome to the work environment survey (1234)" where 1234 is a number identifying the client/survey.
We already rank pretty high because of the way our mailer handles sending the mails. Usually we contact the clients it-dept to get them to whitelist us in their firewall/spamfilter. Would this increase our spamscore in spamfilters?

Comment: What about an additional header, like `X-Client: 1234`?

Comment: I had thought of that, but the bounce doesn't include the original email, does it include all original headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Warning upfront: I've nothing to do with Spam-Filters of any kind...this answer is more based on personal experience and a little guessing Sorry*

That would totally depend on the used Spam-Filter/Analyzer. I, for my part, would say no, it won't. There's no logical reason to consider a subject with numbers in it more likely to be spam then one without. Special characters might be a reason, because sometimes they are used to mask blacklisted words (f.e. via-gra or vi/-\gra etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Very often bounces are detected by using [an unique "From" address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_Address_Tag_Validation), such as `bounces+christian.w=example.net@example.com` or `fce414c4@bounces.example.com` - this will always be present in bounce notifications and will not (should not) have any effect on spamfilters, as long as the sender domain is configured (SPF, all that stuff).